# iOS storing SQLite database

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I’m working on an app for iPad that uses a SQLite database.  I am fairly far along in the development and now I'm trying to solve a problem of how to configure the app so that the database when it is on the iPad can be seen in the Files app.  I have this app that I use named "Accounts2" and in Files on the iPad I can see its database in its own folder.

So far I've added the key **"Application supports iTunes file sharing"** to my info.plist and I can see the file in iTunes and drag the file off to my local disk.  Now I'd like to understand what changes I need to make to be able to see the database file in the Files app..

Also, in the app I've defined the location of the database as being at:

```
let databaseFolder = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString) as String
```

Working with a breakpoint running the app on the iPad I see that the path above has translated to the following

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C3079EB8-2190-4161-A5E4-ABFFB3374393/Documents

so that is where my database is being placed.

I'm wondering if I need to change that location and where that might be...
In files I see the folders like below and I'd like to see my app in there..

[image]

Comment: Have you also added the `Supports opening documents in place / YES` key?

Comment: Thank you for that tip... I added that to my plist but the file doesn't appear in Files yet.  I think it might have to do with where I'm pointing to in my code

Comment: Try it with a new project... Use this code for your view controller: https://pastebin.com/nBGTDAcR ... run the app, and see if it shows up in the Files app/

Comment: Hi sorry, I'm using SwiftUI only in my app and my experience with UIKit is very limited..  I'll try to figure this out though...

Comment: I got the code into my app via creating a func which I called and  at breakpoint it gave me a file URL of file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/638A2E53-36F7-4C72-868D-262BA2334645/Documents/message.txt  and after executing it on the iPad I didn't see messsages.txt in "Files" app.  In my info.plist I have <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
 <true/>
 <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
 <true/>
 <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
 <true/>

Comment: Hmm... not sure what might be going on... I just put up a bare-bones example SwiftUI app here: https://github.com/DonMag/SWUIFilesTest ... works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235240/discussion-between-rpetruzz-and-donmag).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DonMag's suggestion above I wound up adding the keys he suggested to my info.plist and the file now appears in the "Files.app". The keys I added all together were:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
```

See ManagingYourMoney icon below:

[image]